# Making dynamic scope helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, helper, dynamic-scope

Several of my partials can be rendered in two "modes".  If `full_display` is `false`, I don't render several fields.  To make things easy I wanted to make one of the "modes" default - if `full_display` is not defined, treat it as `false`.  I came up with this code:

```
(((not defined?(full_display).nil?) && full_display) || false)
```

Quite a lot to move around.  It would be nice to put it inside a helper or something, but since Ruby has only lexical scope I can't think of any good way to do it.

Bad ideas that I've already tried:

- on the top of the partial do `<% display = long code that is above %>` and use display through the code, but creating local variables in a view looks bad and has to be copied into every partial using `full_display`.
- wrap it inside a string, put it into a helper and use eval(display_helper) in view, but obviously this creates security concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite a convoluted way of saying something as simple as:

```
defined?(full_display) && full_display
```

In Ruby there are two values that are non-true, `nil` and `false`, all others evaluate as true, which includes 0, empty string, among others, that would otherwise evaluate as false in Perl, PHP, and C. Testing with `.nil?` is usually reserved for those rare cases where you want to differentiate between `false` and undefined, and this is sometimes the case with boolean fields where a missing value is different from a false value.

In any case, in the view space it is a lot easier to assign defaults using the or-equals operator `||=` like this:

```
<% full_display ||= false %>
```

That is equivalent to `full_display = full_display || false`. This does two things. First, it defines the `full_display` variable even if it was not previously created, and secondly it ensures that the it will contain a value that is at least `false`, never undefined.

You will see the `||= default` pattern a lot in Ruby code as it's an easy way to assign something in the case where it will be `nil` otherwise.

Comment: That's much better than my code, thanks!  Having dynamically scoped helpers would be even better (and more powerful) though.